Validation of old standard Brazilian and Mercosur vehicle license plates in Django
I'm trying to validate Brazilian boards in Django (Python) for both the old ABC2546 standard and the Mercosul ABC1A35 standard. But when I type the Mercosur standard on the invalid plate.
def validate_placa(placa):
    """
    Valida se a placa do veículo está no formato correto.

    Args:
        placa (str): A placa do veículo a ser validada.

    Returns:
        None se a placa for válida, uma mensagem de erro se não for.
    """
    placa_regex = r'^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}$|^([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{3})([A-Z]{1})$'
    # Formato: ABC-1234
    validator = RegexValidator(regex=placa_regex, message='Placa inválida.')
    try:
        validator(placa)
    except ValidationError as error:
        return error.message

class ClienteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
        fields = '__all__'

    veiculo_placa = forms.CharField(
        validators=[validate_placa],
        max_length=8,
        error_messages={'required': 'Placa é obrigatória.'}
    )

    def validate_data(self, data):
        cleaned_data = super().validate_data(data)
        veiculo_placas = self.data.getlist('veiculo_placa')

        for placa in veiculo_placas:
            error_message = validate_placa(placa)
            if error_message:
                self.add_error('veiculo_placa', error_message)

        return cleaned_data
    

I need to validate both standards

It seems the regex validation for Mercosul is incorrect. Are the parentheses needed?
The correct regex (without "-" characters) should be something like this:
^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9][A-Za-z0-9][0-9]{2}$
You can use online tools to test your regex or even chatGPT is capable of testing and generating them for you.
Hope this helps!

Use parenthesis, so:
placa_regex = r'^([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]{3}[0-9][A-Z][0-9]{2})$'
The Mercosur standard for Brazil [wiki] is thus three A-Z characters, one digit, one A-Z character, and two digits.
